# How does Google Chrome know when to autofill passwords/card number

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a type of subscription manager extension, however I am having trouble determining when a user is on a subscription page.

Ideally I would like to trigger my extension whenever a user is on a page which requires them to fill in their payment info.

The algorithm I am currently implementing searches the dom for content such as "credit card" or "paypal", which works in many cases however it is sometimes getting triggered for pages that aren't subscription pages but just contain credit card somewhere in the content.

How can I improve this algorithm so it acts like that of chromes functionality to autofill credit card numbers, so the action is to trigger the chrome extension when the user is on a payment page, how would I search the DOM for that?

Comment: It's a complex algorithm, see the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/autofill/core/browser/data_model/).

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for sending the link I'll checkout the source code. However I was wondering if there would be a way I could do use the dom to determine it, since I cant actually add to the browser itself using the existing source code(just building a chrome extension)

Comment: They are checking DOM, I suppose, just as well.